# How to make the grid cell invisible and fully excluded from the flow but accessible for accessibility technologies?

Tags: html, css

### Target

Create the below card:

[image]

### Problem

Nothing difficult even for novices until adding of the accessibility variable to the equation.
The user without visual impairments will understand that two labels in the top are the full name and name spell respectively, but respecting the accessibility it is required to specify what means two above labels. `dl` seems to be fine for this case.

```html
<div class="PersonCard" tabindex="0">

  <div class="PersonCard-Avatar"></div>
    
  <dl class="PersonCard-Metadata">
    
    <dt class="PersonCard-Metadata-Key PersonCard-Metadata-Key__Invisible">Official name</dt>
    <dd class="PersonCard-Metadata-Value PersonCard-Metadata-Value__OfficialName">Gutierrez Jaunita</dd>
        
    <dt class="PersonCard-Metadata-Key PersonCard-Metadata-Key__Invisible">Name spell</dt>
    <dd class="PersonCard-Metadata-Value PersonCard-Metadata-Value__OfficialNameSpell">gut'....</dd>
        
    <dt class="PersonCard-Metadata-Key">
      <svg class="PersonCard-Metadata-Key-Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 15.11">
        <path d="M0 0v15.07h20V0zm18.49 1.55L10 8.74 1.52 1.55v-.06h17z" />
      </svg>
      <span class="PersonCard-Metadata-Key-Label">Email</span>
    </dt>
        
    <dd class="PersonCard-Metadata-Value">rogelio.buffington@cumque.gov</dd>
    <dt class="PersonCard-Metadata-Key">
      <svg class="PersonCard-Metadata-Key-Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 17.83 20">
        <path d="M2.68.3l-1 .86 4 4.76 1-.87a1.07 1.07 0 00.12-1.51L4.18.43A1.06 1.06 0 002.68.3zM4.46 13.8c3.72 4.43 9.12 7.35 11.11 5.68l.28-.24-4-4.78a1.08 1.08 0 01-1.22-.16 24.48 24.48 0 01-3-3.14A24.33 24.33 0 015 7.64a1.07 1.07 0 010-1.23L1 1.63l-.2.24C-1.19 3.54.74 9.37 4.46 13.8zM13.46 13.15l-1 .86 4 4.76 1-.87a1.07 1.07 0 00.13-1.51L15 13.28a1.07 1.07 0 00-1.54-.13z" />
      </svg>
      <span class="PersonCard-Metadata-Key-Label">Phone</span>
    </dt>
    <dd class="PersonCard-Metadata-Value">4041386640</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

It to apply the styles, it will looks like:

[image]

The "Official name" and "Name spell" labels must be visibly hidden herewith does not affect to the grid.
The basic initial styles for the grid are:

```
display: grid
grid-template-columns: auto minmax(0, 1fr)
row-gap: 4px
column-gap: 8px
align-items: center
```

### Unacceptable solutions

- The `display: none` is not the acceptable solution because AFAIK it will hide the target item from the accessibility technologies too.
- The `visibility: hidden` will not solve the problem because it only makes the items fully transparent:

[image]

- If we'll apply `width: 0`, `height: 0` and `overflow: hidden` to label which must the invisible and `grid-column: 1 / -1` to the label with official name and the name spell, the additional row will appear:

[image]

Ever with zero height and width, the hidden cells are still getting in the way, however must be fully excluded from the grid flow.

Comment: Are there multiple cards, would this be a list of users/people?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, these cards are intended to be used inside the list.

Answer (score 0):

Adding of `position: absolute` in addition to `width: 0`, `height: 0` and `overflow: hidden` works for me.